# Nothing happen inside my Clojure loop

Tags: loops, clojure, for-loop

I have a small code that doesn't want to work at all when I perform a loop like the following:

```
...

    (defn my-function []
        (println "Hi")   ;this works
        (for [i (range 10)] (println "Hello")  ;this doesn't work!
          )
    )

...
```

I can't understand what the problem is, all the code inside the loop seem to be ignored, while the "Hi" print without problems

I call 'myfunction' through a GUI button event, like this:

```
...
    (.append output-text (with-out-str  (time (my-function))))
...
```

Do you think the problem could reside in the GUI or something else I am missing? Any suggestion?
I know I should use the REPL to test it but it doesn't work with Netbeans... :S

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: It's also worth noting that for in clojure isn't quite the same as a for loop in C. Instead it does something called "list comprehension" - have a look at the docs and play with some examples if you want to figure it out.

Comment: Netbeans clojure support development is on hiatus, I'd suggest to take a look at Eclipse and CounterClockwise.

Comment: @NielsK thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I had various problems trying to install the Eclipse plugin in the end I went for Netbeans,but I will try again. thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `for` macro is lazy, so it will not invoke your function unless the return value is actually needed.

Use the `doseq` function instead. It will force the evaluation of your code, and thus is not lazy. It has the same "syntax" as `for` and allows you to account for side effecting functions such as `println`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of making this is using "dorun", if I remember corretly dorun is pretended for when you make side effects (like println).
The function should look like this:

```
(defn my-function[]
  (println "Hi")
  (dorun (for [i (range 10)] (println "Hello"))))
```